# Add/edit Comments field value in a dynamic table

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm getting data from a SQL table and showing it in a partial view, via the below HTML table:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<h3>Disclosure of Incentives Form</h3>
<br />
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" id="DIFQuestions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Question</th>
            <th> Outcome</th>
            <th> Comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @For Each d In Model.DIFQuestions
            @<tr>
               <td hidden>@d.ID</td>
               <td width="40%" >@d.Description</td>
               <td width="10%">
                <form id="outcomeRadios">
                    <input type="radio" name="DIFPassFail" id="outcomePass" value="True" /> Pass &nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="DIFPassFail" id="outcomeFail" value="Fail" /> Fail
                </form>
              </td>
               <td>
                   <a href="#" class="difcomment" title="Add DIF Information">
                       <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                   </a> &nbsp; Some text here
               </td>
               <td hidden>@d.Order</td>
             </tr>
        Next
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success submitDIFAnswers">Submit</button>
</div>
<br>
```

As can be seen, I'm showing 3 fields: 'Question', 'Outcome' and 'Comments'. 'Question' comes from the SQL table, whereas 'Outcome' and 'Comments' are created dynamically via the for loop.

The font awesome pencil button on the 'Comments' field calls the below modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addeditdifcomments" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Add Comments</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row alert">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea class="difinfo form-control" rows="3" id="difinfo" placeholder="Add DIF information" style="min-width: 200%;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <Button type="button" Class="btn btn-success submitdifcomment">Submit</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble submitting individual notes via the modal for each question. Below is the JQuery that shows the modal, and the one that's meant to save the note text for each row:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".difcomment").click(function () {
        $("#addeditdifcomments").modal('show');
    });


    $(".submitdifcomment").click(function () {

        var difInfo = $(".difinfo").val();

        $(".difcomment").val(difInfo);

        $("#addeditdifcomments").modal('hide');
    });    

});
```

I hope all of this makes sense. Let me know if I need to provide further information.

Any sort of input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 1) maybe you need to reference a specific difcomment element (for example, assign unique ids to <a class="difcomment"> and reference from within $(".submitdifcomment").click() ), and 2) set link text using .text(difInfo) ?

Comment: You want particuler row update click one-row data it's open in popup and changes data and save?

Comment: @yob Thank you, sounds promising. Will give it a go tomorrow and post any updates.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this by assigning the `@d.ID` as an id for my span tag, so each `Comment` would then have a unique id against it.

I would then save the id into a global variable, which I would reassign each time I'm clicking the pencil button on my Comment rows.

JQuery below:

```
    // open modal to submit dif comment
    $(".difcomment").click(function () {           
        questionID = $(this).parent('td').find('span').prop('id')
        $('#addeditdifcomments').modal('show');
    });

    // submit comment
    $(".submitdifcomment").click(function () {

        var difInfo = $(".difinfo").val();
        var path = "span#" + questionID;

        $(path).text(difInfo);

        $(".difinfo").val('');

        $("#addeditdifcomments").modal('hide');
    });
```

Comment: you can also assign and store value of ID in a data attribute: <a href="#" class="difcomment" title="Add DIF Information" data-id="@d.ID">, then onclick assign it to $('#addeditdifcomments').attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id") ), and then reference it from within submit.click.....